# Kubernetes apply nodeSelector via command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, nodeselector

Is there a way to apply a [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) via command? (like `kubectl apply`)

It would be nice if it is applicable on running deployments or namespaces, otherwise applying to running pods is also fine.

Any tips are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the kubectl patch command, like this:

`kubectl patch deployments nginx-deployment -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"nodeSelector": {"kubernetes.io/hostname": "node-2"}}}}}'`

After successful patch all pods of the deployment will be restarted on a node matching the selector.

Comment: Even though I switched to the taint method to get my stuff done, this answer is correct and working. Thanks.